# How to put the getAttr of any selected object inside a textField?

Tags: python, maya

I'm a bit new in scripting and french so exuse me if my explanations are not perfectly clear.

I'm trying to make a script in Maya to manage easily the keys value for animation.

So I created a window reproducing Maya's ChannelBox with another organisation.
And now I'm trying to get the attribute values of a selected object inside the different textField (`transX`, `Y`, `Z`, `rotX`..).

Here is what I have for now :

```
transX_value = cmds.textField( w=100 , h=22 , tx= cmds.getAttr("%s.translateX" %selected) )
```

But when I select my cube for tests and launch my script this error appears:

```
TypeError: Object [u'pCube1'].translateX is invalid
```

So I tried something like this to see if the problem is coming from my formulation:

```
transX_value = cmds.textField( w=100 , h=22 , tx= cmds.getAttr("pCube1.translateX") )
```

It worked and printed the good value inside the textField.

How can I call the attribute of any selected object? I just discovered the `%s` command, so I'm sure that I'm not using it right.

Comment: That error is showing you that `selected` is a list consisting of one element. Do you perhaps mean `selected[0]`?

Comment: Omg I feel so newbie but thanks, that's it.
I didn't knew my 'selected' was a list.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

That's a very common mistake. Your *'selected'* variable holds a list, not a string. You should get the first list value instead, so just change your code like that:

```
transX_value = cmds.textField(w=100, h=22, tx=cmds.getAttr("%s.translateX" % selected[0]))
```

Comment: I haven't seen the question was already answered by Daniel in the comments.

Comment: No problem abadak, I didn't find how to close the topic, I though it would close automatically..
Thanks for your help ;- )